# Spring MVC customized method parameter binding

Tags: java, spring, data-binding, spring-mvc

I'm looking for a way to customize the default Spring MVC parameter binding. Take this method as an example:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/index.html")
public ModelAndView doIndex(@RequestParam String param) {
  ...
```

This is easy, when I have just a `String`that I want to extract from the request. However, I want to populate a more complete object, so that my method looks like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/index.html")
public ModelAndView doIndex(Foo bar) {
  ...
```

What I'm looking for is some way to declare a binding like this;

```
@RequestMapping(value="/index.html")
public ModelAndView doIndex(@FooPopulator Foo bar) {
  ...
```

And have some other kind of implementor (determined by the `@FooPopulator` annotation) that does this:

```
public void doBind(Foo target, ServletRequest originalRequest) {
  target.setX(this.computeStuffBasedOn(originalRequest));
  target.sety(y);
}
```

So far I've found out about the `@InitBinder`binder annotaion but I'm unsure whether that's really the right choice for this scenarion.

What's the best way?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

just a quick thank you and the info, that I've found the "correct" solution to the problem. Spring already provides the [`WebArgumentResolver`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/support/WebArgumentResolver.html) for this scenario.

http://sergialmar.wordpress.com/2011/03/29/extending-handler-method-argument-resolution-in-spring-mvc/

http://scottfrederick.blogspot.com/2011/03/customizing-spring-3-mvcannotation.html

Comment: You could also use a `ModelAttribute` to map form beans

Answer (score 13):

It is very easy. You can use Converters (that work like one way PropertyEditors but are stateless).

See chapter [5.5 Spring 3 Type Conversion](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/spring-framework-reference.html#core-convert) in Spring reference.

If such an converter is registered once, you do not need any additional information, you can simply use

```
@RequestMapping(value="/index.html")
public ModelAndView doIndex(@RequestParam Foo param) {
```

For example a simple converter that load an object by its id:

```
@Component
@CustomConverter //custom qualifyer
public class BUdToUserConverter implements Converter<String, User> {

    @Resource
    private UserDao userDao;

    @Override
    public User convert(String source) {
        Integer id = Integer.parse(source);
        return this.userDao.getByBusinessId(id);
    }
}
```

A "helper" that registers all Beans with @CustomConverter anntoation

```
public class ApplicationConversionServiceFactoryBean extends FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean {

    @Resource
    @CustomConverter
    private List<Converter<?, ?>> customConverter;

     @Override
    protected void installFormatters(final FormatterRegistry registry) {
        super.installFormatters(registry);

        for (Converter<?, ?> converter : customConverter) {
            registry.addConverter(converter);
        }
    }
}
```

How to use it

```
UserController {
...
    @RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView show(@PathVariable("id") User user) {        
        return new ModelAndView("users/show", "user", user);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this works nice for converting a single parameter into a user specific object, however I'd like to traverse the complete `HttpServletRequest` myself and populate the user specific object with values computed depending on the state of the `HttpServletRequest`.