# I am unable to post my form to the post method of my controller

Tags: spring, jsp, http, spring-mvc, servlets

I am trying to submit the form and send the data to the post method of my controller, but all i get is **status 400 error** I am not able to understand why this error is poping when i am able to submit for the post method for the different JSP pages. 
Have I gone wrong somewhere, please help me I am not able to find my mistake

this is my controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "personal" , method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String test(HttpServletRequest request, Model model, HttpServletResponse response, @ModelAttribute("personalDetails") PersonalDetails personalDetails) {

        if(personalDetails==null){
            personalDetails = new PersonalDetails();
        }

        Map referenceData = new HashMap();
        Map<Long, String> salutation = new LinkedHashMap<Long, String>();
        salutation.put(1L, "Mr");
        salutation.put(2L, "Miss");
        salutation.put(3L, "Mrs");


        Map<Long,String> bloodGrp = new LinkedHashMap<Long, String>();
        bloodGrp.put(1L, "A+");
        bloodGrp.put(2L, "B+");

        Map<Long, String> gender = new LinkedHashMap<Long, String>();
        gender.put(1L, "MALE");
        gender.put(2L, "Female");

        Map<Long, String> marriageStatus = new LinkedHashMap<Long, String>();
        marriageStatus.put(1L, "Single");
        marriageStatus.put(2L, "divorsy");

        log.info("Before setting model attributes");

        model.addAttribute("salutationList", salutation);
        model.addAttribute("bloodGrp", bloodGrp);
        model.addAttribute("genderList", gender);
        model.addAttribute("marriageStatus", marriageStatus);
        model.addAttribute("persoanalDetails", personalDetails);

        log.info("after setting model attributes");

        return "personal";


    }

    @RequestMapping(value="personaldetails" , method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String personalDetails(@ModelAttribute("personalDetails") PersonalDetails personalDetails, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response){
        this.personalDetails = personalDetails;
        return "success";
    }
```

My jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>

<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
<title>Generic Tool For Employee</title>
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<!-- Place favicon.ico and apple-touch-icon.png in the root directory -->

<link rel="stylesheet" href="layout/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="layout/css/validator/screen.css">
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="layout/datepicker/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="layout/css/index.css">
<div class="container-fluid">
    <h2>Personal Details</h2>
    <form:form commandName="personalDetails" class="form-horizontal" id="personalDetailsForm" role="form"
        method="POST" action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/personaldetails">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">Personal Information</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="salutation">Salutation</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                        <form:select path="salutation" id="salutation"
                            name="salutation" class="form-control">
                            <!-- <option value="Mr">Mr</option>
                                <option value="Miss">Miss</option>
                                <option value="Mrs">Mrs</option>
                                <option value="Mx">Mx</option> -->
                            <form:options items="${salutationList}" />
                        </form:select>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">First Name</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <form:input path="firstName" id="firstName" type="text"
                            class="form-control charcterClss" name="firstName"
                            placeholder="FIRST NAME" maxlength="250" />
                    </div>
                    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Middle Name</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <form:input path="middleName" id="middleName" type="text"
                            class="form-control charcterClss" name="middleName"
                            placeholder="MIDDLE NAME" maxlength="250" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Last Name</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <form:input path="lastName" id="lastName" type="text"
                            class="form-control charcterClss" name="lastName"
                            placeholder="LAST NAME" maxlength="250" />
                    </div>
                    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Blood group</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <form:select path="bloodGrp" id="bloodGroup"
                            name="bloodGroup" class="form-control">
                            <!--  <option></option>
                                <option>O +ve</option>
                                <option>O -ve</option>
                                <option>B +ve</option>
                                <option>B -ve</option>
                                <option>A +ve</option>
                                <option>A -ve</option>
                                <option>AB +ve</option>
                                <option>AB -ve</option> -->
                            <form:options items="${bloodGrp}" />
                        </form:select>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Gender</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <form:select path="gender" id="gender" name="gender"
                            class="form-control">
                            <!--    <option value="Male">Male</option>
                                <option value="FeMale">Fe-Male</option>
                                <option value="Neutral">Transgender</option> -->
                            <form:options items="${genderList}" />
                        </form:select>
                    </div>
                    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email Id</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <form:input path="emailId" class="form-control" type="text"
                            name="personalEmail" id="personalEmail"
                            placeholder="Personal Email" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Contact Number</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <form:input path="contactNo" class="form-control" type="text"
                            id="personalPhoneNno" name="personalPhoneNno"
                            placeholder="Personal Contact" />
                    </div>
                    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Alternative Contact
                        Number</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <form:input path="alterContactNo" class="form-control" type="text"
                            id="alternativePhoneNo" name="alternativePhoneNo"
                            placeholder="Alternative Contact" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Date of Birth</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <form:input path="dob" type="text" class="form-control datepicker"
                            placeholder="DOB" id="dOb" name="dOb" />
                    </div>
                    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Birth Place</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <form:input path="birthPlace" type="text"
                            class="form-control charcterClss" placeholder="PLACE YOU BORN"
                            id="birthPlace" name="birthPlace" maxlength="250" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Nationality</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <form:input path="nationality" type="text"
                            class="form-control charcterClss" placeholder="NATIONALITY"
                            id="nationality" name="nationality" />
                    </div>
                    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Religion</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <form:input path="religion" type="text"
                            class="form-control charcterClss" placeholder="RELIGION"
                            id="religion" name="religion" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Marital Status</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <form:select path="marriageDetails" id="maritalStatus" name="maritalStatus"
                            class="form-control">
                            <!-- <option value="single">Single</option>
                            <option value="married">Married</option>
                            <option value="divorcee">Divorcee</option> -->
                            <form:options items="${marriageStatus}"/>
                        </form:select>
                    </div>
                    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Date of Wedding</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <form:input path="dow" type="text" class="form-control datepicker"
                            placeholder="WEDDING DATE" id="weedingDate" name="weedingDate"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-footer">
                <input class="submit btn btn-default" type="submit" value="Submit">
            </div>
        </div>
        </form:form>
</div>

<!-- SCRIPTS -->
<script src="js/vendors/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/vendors/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/vendors/bootstrap-3.3.5.js"></script>
<script src="datepicker/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/index.js"></script>
<script src="js/personal.js"></script>
```

and this is my model

```
@Entity
@Table(name="TB_PERSONAL_DETAILS")
public class PersonalDetails implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name="PERSON_ID")
    private Long personId;

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER, cascade=CascadeType.DETACH)
    @JoinColumn(name="SALUTATION_ID")
    private SalutationMaster salutation;

    @Column(name="FIRST_NAME")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name="MIDDLE_NAME")
    private String middleName;

    @Column(name="LAST_NAME")
    private String lastName;

    @OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER,cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="BLOOD_GRP_ID")
    private BloodGrpMaster bloodGrp;

    @OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER,cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="GENDER_ID")
    private GenderMaster gender;

    @Column(name="EMAIL_ID")
    private String emailId;

    @Column(name="CONTACT_NO")
    private String contactNo;

    @Column(name="ALTERNATE_CONTACT_NO")
    private String alterContactNo;

    @Column(name="DATE_OF_BIRTH")
    private Date dob;

    @Column(name="BIRTH_PLACE")
    private String birthPlace;

    @Column(name="RELIGION")
    private String religion;

    @Column(name="NATIONALITY")
    private String nationality;

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER,cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="MARRIAGE_DETAILS_ID")
    private MarriageMaster marriageDetails;

    @Column(name="DOW")
    private Date dow;

    @OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER,cascade=CascadeType.ALL,mappedBy="personalDetails")
    private EmployeeDetails employeeDetails;


    public PersonalDetails() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public Long getPersonId() {
        return personId;
    }
    public void setPersonId(Long personId) {
        this.personId = personId;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }
    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }
    public String getMiddleName() {
        return middleName;
    }
    public void setMiddleName(String middleName) {
        this.middleName = middleName;
    }
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }
    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
    public BloodGrpMaster getBloodGrp() {
        return bloodGrp;
    }
    public void setBloodGrp(BloodGrpMaster bloodGrp) {
        this.bloodGrp = bloodGrp;
    }

    public GenderMaster getGender() {
        return gender;
    }
    public void setGender(GenderMaster gender) {
        this.gender = gender;
    }
    public Date getDob() {
        return dob;
    }
    public void setDob(Date dob) {
        this.dob = dob;
    }
    public String getBirthPlace() {
        return birthPlace;
    }
    public void setBirthPlace(String birthPlace) {
        this.birthPlace = birthPlace;
    }
    public String getReligion() {
        return religion;
    }
    public void setReligion(String religion) {
        this.religion = religion;
    }
    public String getNationality() {
        return nationality;
    }
    public void setNationality(String nationality) {
        this.nationality = nationality;
    }

    public SalutationMaster getSalutation() {
        return salutation;
    }

    public void setSalutation(SalutationMaster salutation) {
        this.salutation = salutation;
    }

    public EmployeeDetails getEmployeeDetails() {
        return employeeDetails;
    }

    public void setEmployeeDetails(EmployeeDetails employeeDetails) {
        this.employeeDetails = employeeDetails;
    }


    /**
     * give the marital details of the employee
     * @return
     */
    public MarriageMaster getMarriageDetails() {
        return marriageDetails;
    }

    /**
     * set the marital details of the employee
     * @param marriageDetails
     */
    public void setMarriageDetails(MarriageMaster marriageDetails) {
        this.marriageDetails = marriageDetails;
    }

    public Date getDow() {
        return dow;
    }

    public void setDow(Date dow) {
        this.dow = dow;
    }

    public String getEmailId() {
        return emailId;
    }

    public void setEmailId(String emailId) {
        this.emailId = emailId;
    }

    public String getContactNo() {
        return contactNo;
    }

    public void setContactNo(String contactNo) {
        this.contactNo = contactNo;
    }

    public String getAlterContactNo() {
        return alterContactNo;
    }

    public void setAlterContactNo(String alterContactNo) {
        this.alterContactNo = alterContactNo;
    }

}
```

Thank you in advance for going through my issue and giving your best on that.

Comment: did you try with this ... action="personaldetails" instead of action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/personaldetails"

Comment: Check exact path used on submit via, say, chrome developer tools. I assume it might bring you to some other place

Comment: YES I did still the same error

Comment: Remote Address:127.0.0.1:8080
Request URL:http://localhost:8080/eob-web/personaldetails
Request Method:POST
Status Code:400 Bad Request


Ya i also saw the url using chrome developer tool. The url is correct. But I still dont understand why I am getting 400 Bad Request

Comment: your problem is the databiding of the form data and your object.

for example the salutation field and bloodGroup are sending as String in the request Object but in your PersonalDetails they are objects and not String.

I think you should make a custom data binder

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6519322/spring-mvc-customized-method-parameter-binding it can help you.